# Scale Responsive Logo and Keep Ratio

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've got this logo I'm trying to use on a responsive site, but I can't figure out how to have it so it fills the full width of its parent element while maintaining its ratio in height.

When you start resizing the browser window, the logo gets smaller in width but its height doesn't scale properly. Is there a way to maintain this.

Here's my CSS for the logo element:

```
h1 {
    width: 100%;
            height: auto;
    background: url(http://images.uncyclomedia.co/uncyclopedia/en/thumb/c/ce/Coca-Cola_logo.svg/800px-Coca-Cola_logo.svg.png) no-repeat top left orange;
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent: -999999px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 270px;
}
```

This is the problem I'm having. Look at all that extra space below the
logo.

[image]

And here's a CodePen with an example of my issue:

http://codepen.io/realph/pen/LAFsi

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a padding trick (see [CSS-square container](http://css-tricks.com/css-animation-tricks/)) to do what you want with one image

```
h1 {
    background: url(http://images.uncyclomedia.co/uncyclopedia/en/thumb/c/ce/Coca-Cola_logo.svg/800px-Coca-Cola_logo.svg.png) no-repeat top left orange;
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent: -999999px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    display:block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4E4Nr/)

Comment: That @ZachSaucier, is an amazing trick! Thank you for that answer. Incredible!

Comment: The trick is quite handy for many different cases. Incredibly indeed, though I didn't create it originally

Comment: Thank you again! Huge lightbulb moment when I realised what it was doing.

Comment: The `height:0` is a crazy concept, haha. It's an awesome one though